# elastic search spring boot

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am trying to connect to Elastic Cluster. ES version 6.2.0 and client version 6.2.0

when i try to connect i get the below error.

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'client' defined in class path resource [com/dct/search/sync/ElasticSearch/ElasticSearchConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.elasticsearch.client.Client]: Factory method 'client' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/elasticsearch/common/logging/Loggers

The error is "org/elasticsearch/common/logging/Loggers" not "org/apache/logging/log4j/Logger"

Can someone please help me out.

Comment: How do you build your project? Do you have all necessary jars on the build path?

Comment: I fixed this issue. In order to support the above issue I had to use Spring 2.0.0RC1 and all the other projects depended on it.